# Unique row in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a "Subscriber" table :

| S_ID | con |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 |
| 2 | 222 |
| 3 | 333 |
| 4 | 444 |
| 5 | 555 |

also,I have two tables -  "product_subscriber" and "service_subscriber" and prod_name and ser_name have the same name

product_subscriber:

| s_id | id | prod_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | offer 1 |
| 1 | 21 | offer 2 |
| 2 | 20 | offer 1 |
| 3 | 21 | offer 2 |

service_subscriber:

| s_id | id | ser_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | offer 1 |
| 1 | 11 | offer 2 |
| 3 | 11 | offer 2 |
| 3 | 10 | offer 1 |
| 5 | 10 | offer 1 |

I want to get table like this:

| s_id | ser_name | prod_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | offer 1 | offer 1 |
| 1 | offer 2 | offer 2 |
| 2 | offer 1 |  |
| 3 | offer 2 | offer 2 |
| 3 |  | offer 1 |
| 5 |  | offer 1 |

Below is the code, but for users who have more than two offers, for example s_id = 1,
Incorrectly matched, something like that

| s_id | ser_name | prod_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | offer 1 | offer 2 |
| 1 | offer 2 | offer 2 |
| 1 | offer 2 | offer 1 |
| 1 | offer 1 | offer 1 |

```
SELECT p.pid,
       p.mobile,
       o.of_name,
       s.ser_name 
FROM   person p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN offer o
       ON p.pid = o.pid
       LEFT OUTER JOIN service s
       ON p.pid = s.pid
WHERE  o.pid IS NOT NULL
OR     s.pid IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       ps.prod_name,
       ss.ser_name
FROM   subscriber s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN product_subscriber ps
       ON s.s_id = ps.s_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN service_subscriber ss
       ON (   s.s_id = ss.s_id
          AND (ps.s_id IS NULL OR ps.id = ss.id + 10))
WHERE  ps.s_id IS NOT NULL
OR     ss.s_id IS NOT NULL
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE subscriber (S_ID, con) AS
SELECT 1, 111 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 333 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 444 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 555 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE product_subscriber (s_id, id, prod_name) AS
SELECT 1, 20, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 21, 'offer 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 20, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 21, 'offer 2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE service_subscriber (s_id, id, ser_name) AS
SELECT 1, 10, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 11, 'offer 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 11, 'offer 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 10, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 10, 'offer 1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | S_ID | CON | PROD_NAME | SER_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 111 | offer 1 | offer 1 |
> | 1 | 111 | offer 2 | offer 2 |
> | 2 | 222 | offer 1 | *null* |
> | 3 | 333 | offer 2 | offer 2 |
> | 5 | 555 | *null* | offer 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7d14d76f10844e9bb4818c0dfffc0df2)*

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks as if you need to include additional join condition - a "virtual" column created by `row_number` analytic function (at least, that's what I figured out looking at desired output); something like this:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  subscriber (s_id, con) as
  3    (select 1, 111 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 222 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 333 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 444 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 555 from dual
  8    ),
  9  product_subscriber (s_id, id, prod_name) as
 10    (select 1, 20, 'offer 1' from dual union all
 11     select 1, 21, 'offer 2' from dual union all
 12     select 2, 20, 'offer 1' from dual union all
 13     select 3, 21, 'offer 2' from dual
 14    ),
 15  service_subscriber (s_id, id, ser_name) as
 16    (select 1, 10, 'offer 1' from dual union all
 17     select 1, 11, 'offer 2' from dual union all
 18     select 3, 11, 'offer 2' from dual union all
 19     select 3, 10, 'offer 1' from dual union all
 20     select 5, 10, 'offer 1' from dual
 21    ),
 22  --
```

Query begins here; CTEs just *calculate* row numbers in an outer join of `subscriber` and another table:

```
 23  temp_ps as
 24    (select s.s_id, ps.id, ps.prod_name,
 25            row_number() over (partition by s.s_id order by ps.id desc) rn
 26     from subscriber s left join product_subscriber ps on ps.s_id = s.s_id
 27    ),
 28  temp_ss as
 29    (select s.s_id, ss.id, ss.ser_name,
 30            row_number() over (partition by s.s_id order by ss.id desc) rn
 31     from subscriber s left join service_subscriber ss on ss.s_id = s.s_id
 32    )
 33  select ss.s_id, ss.ser_name, ps.prod_name
 34  from temp_ss ss left join temp_ps ps on ps.s_id = ss.s_id and nvl(ps.rn, -1) = nvL(ss.rn, -1)
 35  order by ss.s_id, ss.ser_name, ps.prod_name;

      S_ID SER_NAME   PROD_NAME
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 offer 1    offer 1
         1 offer 2    offer 2
         2            offer 1
         3 offer 1
         3 offer 2    offer 2
         4
         5 offer 1

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```